# 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, web-services, uwp

I'm trying to build a UWP app that consumes a wsdl web service.

If I add a service reference to my project (as described here - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/consume-web-service-in-metro-style-app/) the service is added, but fails to build with errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
```

I'm fairly new to UWP, is it possible that the "Web" interface is simply not present? How would I be able to tell if something is present or not in the UWP world?

Comment: The target is "Holographic" if that makes any difference, but AFAIK I can reference the "Desktop" extensions

Comment: There is a new add-in to consume web services for .NET Core, so you should search for it and use that to generate a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no `System.Web` namespace in UWP. [System.Web Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web(v=vs.110).aspx) is a traditional .NET Framework namespace and is usually used in ASP.NET. It can't be used in UWP apps. For the .Net APIs that are supported in UWP, please see [.NET for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185501.aspx).

However, I'm not sure why you need this namespace in your UWP app. I followed the article you've mentioned. Although there is a minor mistake, but it doesn't use `System.Web` namespace and it can work. So I'd suggest you check your code and find where you used the `System.Web` namespace.

You can also check [my sample at GitHub](https://github.com/Z-Jay/UWPConsumeWebService). It works well in HoloLens Emulator.
[image]

Comment: The C# code generated by the "Add Service References" had those references in it.  Although - I admit - I didn't actually follow along the tutorial, I skipped straight to adding the webservice to a Unity project (that plays in Hololens).  I also tried using the wsdl cmd line tool to generate the code, but with the same result.

Comment: In any case, thanks for your answer.  I figured something like this - .Net could do with a haircut - but for some reason I couldn't find a simple, definitive answer in my googling yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to use the EWS managed API in UWP as it requires the System.Web namespace.  If you can pinpoint the exact feature of the webservice you need, it is possible to re-implement the methods that require System.Web and use a similar feature in System.Net.

Obviously this is harder than just using something already built in, but you can try to find exactly what feature of System.Web you need.